# How to modify VBO data

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, vbo

I am learning LWJGL so i can start working on my game. In order to learn LWJGL I got the  idea to implement the map builder so I can get comfortable with graphics programming. Now, for the map creation tool I need to draw new elements or draw the old one's with different coordinates.

*Let me explain this:*

My game will be a 2D scroller. The map will be consisting of multiple rectangles ( 2 strip triangles). When I click my left-mouse button i want to start the rectangle and when I release it I want to stop the rectangle bottom-right at that position.

As I want to use VBOs I want to know how to modify data inside the VBO based on user input.
Should i have a copy of a vertex array and then add the whole array to the VBO at each user input? How is usually implemented the VBO update?

Comment: Check out: [glBufferSubData](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml). Though, it's probably easier to just make the buffer again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For small data like this, you want [glBufferSubData](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml), sweet and simple :)

Later on you probably should look into [glMapBuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml) though, as it is how you work with data larger than a few kilobytes quickly.

Comment: Note that you should use [glInvalidateBufferData](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glInvalidateBuffer) as appropriate, or for older GL, use the trick of calling `glBufferData` first with a `NULL` address and 0 length. This will allow the GPU to intelligently handle your data updates without stalling in the event you are updating the buffer while the GPU is still drawing from it.

Comment: to supplement sean's recommendations, also investigate glMapBufferRange and amd's pinned memory